# check if in binary tree exist two elements whom difference is d. O(n)

Tags: pseudocode

Traverse Tree size of n In-order and copy elements into array size of n one by one.
This way you get a sorted array in time complexity of O(n).
if array is A[1...n] then declare i=1 and j=2.

```
while(j>i)
{
   if(A[j]-A[i] = d)
     return true;
   else if(A[j]-A[i] < d)
     j=j+1;
   else if(A[j] > d)
     i=i+1;
}
return false;
```

Time complexity O(n)

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: I'm sorry I was tired when I posted this.
Should I delete it?

Comment: Instead of deleting, you could [edit] the post to clarify what exactly you're asking